# ZF2 - Get Data From Doctrine Orm In Dao Layer

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

My Controller :

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Admin\Controller;
use Admin\Service;

class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $CrudService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('CrudService');

        return new ViewModel(
            array('list'=> $CrudService->getList())
        );
    }
}
```

Service Layer :

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Service;
use Admin\Dao;


class CrudService
{
    public function getList()
    {

        $CrudDao=new Dao\CrudDao();
        $list=$CrudDao->getList();
        return $list;
    }
}
```

Dao Layer :

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Dao;


class CrudDao
{
    public function getList()
    {

        return
            $this->getServiceLocator()->
            get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->
            getRepository('Admin\Entity\ProductEntity')
                ->findAll();

    }
}
```

every things is good work But My Problem is **Dao Layer**. that give me  This 
Error : **not Found get Service Locator Class**

I want get data From Doctrine in Dao Layer and Call Dao Method in Service Layer And Next Call Service With getServiceLocator in Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inject all dependencies and use the service manager to get the classes.

In you Module.php you have to register and inject the dependencies:

```
class Module
{
    // ...

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        $factories = [
            'Admin\Dao\CrudDao' = function (ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'),
                return new CrudDao($entityManager);
            },
            'Admin\Service\CrudService' = function (ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                return new CrudService($serviceManager);
            }
        ];

        return $factories;
    }
}
```

The Dao will receive the EntityManager:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Dao;

class CrudDao
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getList()
    {

        return
            $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository('Admin\Entity\ProductEntity')
            ->findAll();

    }
}
```

Your CrudService will receive the Service manager, then you can get the CrudDao:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Service;
use Admin\Dao;


class CrudService
{
    public function __construct($serviceManager)
    {
        $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        $CrudDao= $this->serviceManager->get('Admin\Dao\CrudDao');
        $list = $CrudDao->getList();
        return $list;
    }
}
```

And your controller:

```
<?php
namespace Admin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Admin\Controller;
use Admin\Service;

class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $CrudService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Admin\Service\CrudService');

        return new ViewModel(
            array('list'=> $CrudService->getList())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for useful help ,this solution should be work but Zend give me this Error :Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Admin\Service\CrudService

Comment: thanks ,change getServiceConfig() Body method with this Code And Work For me :  return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Admin\Dao\CrudDao' =>  function (ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                $entityManager = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
                return new CrudDao($entityManager);
            },
                //I need to get this to the list of groups
    'Admin\Service\CrudService' => function (ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                return new CrudService($serviceManager);
            },
            ),
        );